# How is it that binding a method inside the constructor is different from binding it inside the call to React.cloneElement?

Tags: reactjs

```
import React , {Component} from 'react'

class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <Buttons>
        <button value='A'>A</button>
        <button value='B'>B</button>
        <button value='C'>C</button>
      </Buttons>
    )
  }
}


class Buttons extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state= {
      selected: 'none'
    }
  }

  selectItem(selected){
    this.setState( { selected } )
  }

  render(){
    let fn = (child) => (
      React.cloneElement( child , {
          // this only change is the call to bind here  
          onClick: this.selectItem.bind(this , child.props.value)
        } 
      )
    )
    let items = React.Children.map(this.props.children , fn)
    return(
      <div>
        <h3>
          you have selected: {this.state.selected}
        </h3>
        {items}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

---

```
import React , {Component} from 'react'

class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <Buttons>
        <button value='A'>A</button>
        <button value='B'>B</button>
        <button value='C'>C</button>
      </Buttons>
    )
  }
}


class Buttons extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state= {
      selected: 'none'
    }
    // here I added the binding on the constructor . 
    this.selectItem = this.selectItem.bind(this)
  }

  selectItem(selected){
    this.setState( { selected } )
  }

  render(){
    let fn = (child) => (
      React.cloneElement( child , {
          // this only change is the call to bind here  
          onClick: this.selectItem(child.props.value)
        } 
      )
    )
    let items = React.Children.map(this.props.children , fn)
    return(
      <div>
        <h3>
          you have selected: {this.state.selected}
        </h3>
        {items}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

when adding the `this` binding inside the callback that is passed to `React.cloneElement` everything works just find (first code example)

but

when adding the binding up top in the constructor seems to invoke an infinite loop of some sort . I still can't figure out why ? 
what is the difference between the two ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diffrence in the two cases is the parameter passed to a `onClick`

In first case

```
onClick: this.selectItem.bind(this,child.props.value)
```

You are passing a function to the `onClick` handler

In the second case

```
onClick: this.selectItem(child.props.value)
```

What happends is that you are calling a function, but the `onClick` receives it a parameter returned from the function which is basically `null` and hence it creates a problem. The reason behind your component going into an infinite loop is that you are in case of `onClick: this.selectItem(child.props.value)` , as I said `this.selectItem(child.props.value)` returns a value to the onClick handler whereas it expects a function and hence everytime your `render` is called the function will be called for the return value and since your are using `setState` in the same function, it will trigger a rerender after the state has mutated and hence go into an infinite loop

Comment: I tried to `console.log(this)` when binding was happening in the constructor I got the same thing as when binding  on the `onClick`  , now here is the weird thing when binding in the constructor it calls the function automatically without me pressing any buttons  ?

Comment: Added an explanation for that. Check the updated answer